# .click function not working as planned with multiple calls

Tags: jquery

I have a table with four tiles, the id's being firsttile, secondtile, thirdtile and fourtile.  I have a group of images with the class .thumbnail and what I want is to click on the thumbnail and have that image placed in the first tile, then click on another thumbnail and have it go into the second tile, etc.  I'll worry about resizing later. Also, in this code, I'm putting the same jpg (amb.jpg) in any tile, no matter what thumbnail is clicked for the moment for simplicity. The following code does almost work except when I click a thumbnail, the amb.jpg  gets placed in all 4 of the tiles at once instead of the one I've designated with the .css code that follows the click.  What I want is for it to be placed in the first tile, then when I click on a thumbnail again, get the amb.jpg placed in the second tile, etc.  That's why I've written the same code 4 times.    Where am I going wrong?  Thanks.

```
   <script>
   $('.thumbnail').live ("click", function()   {


       $("#firsttile").css('background-image', 'url(amb.jpg)');
       return false;
     });
     $('.thumbnail').live ("click", function()   {


       $("#secondtile").css('background-image', 'url(amb.jpg)');
       return false;
     });

       $('.thumbnail').live ("click", function()   {


       $("#thirdtile").css('background-image', 'url(amb.jpg)');
       return false;
     }); 

       $('.thumbnail').live ("click", function()   {


       $("#fourthtile").css('background-image', 'url(amb.jpg)');
       return false;
     });             

   </script>
```

Comment: You should use a current version of jQuery, and then that code wouldn't work at all, but at least you'd be up to date.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what version of jQuery that you are using, but `.live()` has been deprecated and removed from recent versions.

Comment: And to be helpful, the reason it will not work is because "live" has been changed to "on"

Comment: which is a little over two years old.

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter to keep track of which tile you want to update.

```
var tiles = [ "#firsttile", "#secondtile", "#thirdtile", "#fourthtile" ];
var curTile = 0;

$(document).on("click", ".thumbnail a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (curTile < tiles.length) {
        $(tiles[curTile]).css('background-image', 'url(' +
        $(this).attr('href') + ')');
    }
    curTile++;
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7RCa9/6/)

Comment: This works very well, thanks, though var curTile should start at -1 so that the first interation of curTile++ will get me to the first tile, because of the zero indexing.

Comment: Oops. I moved the increment to after the indexing.

Comment: If I may ask another question.  I really don't want to fill my tiles with the same jpg when all is said and done.  I've tried some jquery to take the images in the thumbnails, which are href links, and have them appear in the tiles but with no success.  Just how can I take the current href of the thumbnail I click on and turn it into a background image to be used in the tile css.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happened but when I pasted in your updated code, now when I click on a thumbnail, nothing changes in the tiles, and a new page opens up in the browser with the thumbnail photo, as if the return false didn't execute.  A copied and pasted the code exactly as you put it in.  I even put back the url for amb.jpg which seemed to work before in putting that jpg in each tile, but now I'm back to square one.  Can't see anything wrong.  Can you?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: here is entire script, and I should add that when I click on a thumbnail, it is the thumbnail's picture that opens in a new page.

Comment: <script>


var tiles = [ "#firsttile", "#secondtile", "#thirdtile", "#fourthtile" ];
var curTile = 0;

$(document).on("click", ".thumbnail", function() {
    if (curTile < tiles.length) {
        $(tiles[curTile]).css('background-image', 'url('amb.jpg')');
    }
    curTile++;
    return false;
});

</script>

Comment: Don't try to put long codes in comments. It's impossible to read without formatting. Please make a jsfiddle like I asked.

Comment: I've redone your fiddle so the HTML, CSS, and JS are in the appropriate sections. But you need to put absolute URLs in your HREF and SRC attributes so that the images can be loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7RCa9/3/

Comment: I see the problem. You're attaching the click handler to the DIV, not the A. So clicking on the A follows the link normally.

Comment: how can I fix that and it's crazy that it worked before with the same code?

Comment: The other problem is that when you went back to `amb.jpg`, you had a syntax error, so none of the JS was running.

Comment: I have these jpgs locally so I don't know how I can share them with you but you see in the jfiddle that when you click on one of the placeholders for the thumbnails down below, a new page opens.

Comment: You always need to check the Javascript console for errors when it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thanks so much.  I'm a newbie at a lot of this and I'm going to spend quite a while going through that new answer and hopefully learn a lot.  Thanks again!

Comment: Don't know if you're still looking at these comments, but in your script, you have both e.preventdefault() and return(false).  Do you really need the return(false)?  Thanks

Comment: Probably not. I added the preventDefault while I was troubleshooting. There's no harm in the redundancy, though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this adds the image to all of them is because you attached the click even using the selector .thumbnail.  All of them have it, so when you click on, all of the events fire.  In the delegate function, just add event as a param... then add the css to the actual html element clicked.  In your case, change "on" back to "live" in my sample code.  I know the code you put up may also just be a sample, but you should also put this in a document ready block as the html may not be rendered and ready to attach event to when this JS is called.

```
$('.thumbnail').on("click", function(event)   {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(event.currentTarget).css('background-image', 'url(amb.jpg)');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget` will be the thumbnail he clicked on, not one of the tiles he wants to update.